# PHP YouTube API, get upload status

Tags: php, cakephp, zend-framework, youtube

I'm having a heck of a time trying to get the status of a uploaded video to YouTube. I've followed the bellow URL to setup a CRON job that would send videos to YouTube, get a response; preferably with the YouTube ID so I can save this in a database. Down side is I can not get this to work.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.gdata.youtube.html

My Code: (Which is basically copy and past from the above URL)

```
    function upload($filename, $options = array()) {
        $default = array_merge(
            array(
                'username' => 'USERNAME',
                'password' => 'PASSWORD',
                'service' => 'youtube',
                'client' => null,
                'source' => 'YouTube Component',
                'loginToken' => null,
                'loginCaptcha' => null,
                'authenticationURL' => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin',
                'applicationId' => 'YouTube Component',
                'clientId' => 'YouTube Component',
                'developerKey' => 'DEVELOPERS-KEY',
                'content_type' => 'video/quicktime',
                'title' => null,
                'description' => null, 
                'category' => null,
                'tags' => null,
            ),
            (array)$options
        );
        extract($default);

        $this->controller->Zend->loadClass('Zend_Gdata_YouTube'); 
        $this->controller->Zend->loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin'); 

        $httpClient = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient(
            $username,
            $password,
            $service,
            $client,
            $source,
            $loginToken,
            $loginCaptcha,
            $authenticationURL
        );

        $yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient, $applicationId, $clientId, $developerKey);

        $myVideoEntry = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry();

        $filesource = $yt->newMediaFileSource($filename);
        $filesource->setContentType($content_type);
        $filesource->setSlug($filename); 
        $myVideoEntry->setMediaSource($filesource);
        $myVideoEntry->setVideoTitle($title);
        $myVideoEntry->setVideoDescription($description);
        $myVideoEntry->setVideoCategory($category);
        $myVideoEntry->SetVideoTags($tags);
        $myVideoEntry->setVideoPrivate();
        $uploadUrl = 'http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads';

        try {
            $newEntry = $yt->insertEntry($myVideoEntry, $uploadUrl, 'Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry');
        } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException $httpException) {
            echo $httpException->getRawResponseBody();
        } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

        try {
            $control = $myVideoEntry->getControl();
        } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

        if ($control instanceof Zend_Gdata_App_Extension_Control) {
            if ($control->getDraft() != null && $control->getDraft()->getText() == 'yes') {
                $state = $myVideoEntry->getVideoState();
                if ($state instanceof Zend_Gdata_YouTube_Extension_State) {
                    print 'Upload status: ' . $state->getName() .' '. $state->getText();
                } else {
                    print 'Not able to retrieve the video status information' .' yet. ' . "Please try again shortly.\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The above works in every way, minus the fact that I always get "Not able to retrieve the video status information...". What am I doing wrong? I've been staring at this for hours so I imagine its something simple that I've missed.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't to terribly far off with completing this. The answer was to replace all of the return code with (customized a bit because I need a return value as this is a CakePHP component.):

```
        $state = $newEntry->getVideoState();

        if ($state) {
            $response['id'] = $newEntry->getVideoId();
        } else {
            $response['error'] = "Not able to retrieve the video status information yet. " . 
                "Please try again later.\n";
        }

        return $response;
```